# Disable SSR in donejs

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, donejs

SSR is a cool donejs feature. But in my current project I have no use of it because I am building a page which gets wrapped in a cordova app only.

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "abc.org",
  "homepage": "www.abc.org",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/xyz/xyz.git"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "xyz",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "url": "www.abc.org"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "testee test.html --browsers firefox --reporter Spec",
    "start": "done-serve --port 8080",
    "develop": "done-serve --develop --port 8080",
    "build": "node build"
  },
  "main": "spotwizard/index.stache!done-autorender",
  "files": [
    "src"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "",
    "donejs-app"
  ],
  "steal": {
    "main": "spotwizard/index.stache!done-autorender",
    "directories": {
      "lib": "src"
    },
    "configDependencies": [
      "live-reload",
      "node_modules/can-zone/register"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "done-css",
      "done-component",
      "steal-less",
      "steal-stache"
    ],
    "envs": {
      "server-production": {
        "renderingBaseURL": "/dist"
      }
    },
    "serviceBaseURL": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajax-request": "^1.2.3",
    "can-ajax": "^1.1.4",
    "can-component": "^3.3.10",
    "can-connect": "^1.5.9",
    "can-define": "^1.5.5",
    "can-route": "^3.2.3",
    "can-route-pushstate": "^3.1.2",
    "can-set": "^1.3.2",
    "can-stache": "^3.11.1",
    "can-view-autorender": "^3.1.1",
    "can-zone": "^0.6.13",
    "done-autorender": "^1.4.0",
    "done-component": "^1.0.0",
    "done-css": "^3.0.1",
    "done-serve": "^1.5.0",
    "generator-donejs": "^1.0.7",
    "http-parser-js": "^0.4.10",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "steal": "^1.5.15",
    "steal-less": "^1.2.0",
    "steal-stache": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "can-fixture": "^1.1.1",
    "donejs-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "funcunit": "^3.2.0",
    "steal-qunit": "^1.0.1",
    "steal-tools": "^1.9.1",
    "testee": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

The app has been scaffolded with the usual donejs cli commands:

```
donejs add app abc
```

By doing so SSR is by default active which is not desired in my particular case.

Is there a configuration switch to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have `require("done-ssr")` anywhere in your code?  Start by turning that off.

Comment: No, in my code I do not load done-ssr. I guess donejs does that in done-serve but I actually don't want do edit code in this dependency ("done-serve": "^1.5.0").